# How to make realtime password validation for flutter , with linearPercentIndicator?

Tags: flutter, dart

[Check the link below, for more details, but I want validation to work on realtime , as I go on typing in the textfield.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TABvCQmNrWA6TEYy2qf7BfsE3cuMHZyG/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: So some part of code you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [flutter_pw_validator](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pw_validator) dependency for this if you don't want to implement validation rules by yourself. They are also provide guideline text for user to understand what is missing in their password.